# RStudio Desktop: r is taking longer to start than usual

Tags: rstudio, startup

I have been running rstudio desktop for several months but recently I went to start it and it says "r is taking longer to start than usual" and the loading wheel just spins and spins but it never opens.[trys to load but never opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ist.png) I am running the latest versions of R and Rstudio as of this post. I am running windows 10 as my operating system.

I have tried deleting .Rdata, Rprofile.site, .Rprofile and .Renviron files. I have uninstalled and reinstalled both R and Rstudio to the default locations. I have tried clearing the global environment and the DNS cache. When I try to start R with an OS command it says "R is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." Yet if I use the short cut I am able to open base R.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be much appreciated I have been trying to fix this for days but have found nothing but dead ends. Please let me know if there is more data I can provide that would be useful in resolving this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove remove all config files like .Rprofile, .Renviron, and .Rdata from your working directory, this worked for my case.
[More details](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200488508-RStudio-Desktop-Will-Not-Start)

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this for posterity, the OP of this question reported being able to resolve their issue in another forum. Their solution was:

> I had to uninstall R and Rstudio
> Launch "run" enter %localappdata% and delete all files pertaining to R or Rstudio
> Launch "run" enter %appdata% go to roaming and delete the Rstudio files there
> Got to where I had my R packages installed and delete those
> Then I had to reinstall R and RStudio

I ran into this same strange error and I was able to resolve it without touching R or my packages:

1. Uninstall RStudio
2. Launch "run" enter %localappdata% and delete all files pertaining to Rstudio
3. Launch "run" enter %appdata% go to roaming and delete the Rstudio files there
4. Reinstall RStudio

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was the fact that my default working directory no longer existed. You can check this by going to Tools > Global Options and changing the path for the Default working directory.